# Laravel Validation Unique

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com um formulário de cadastro, e nele existem informações para popular duas tabelas:

- Usuário(User);
- Embarcador(Sender).

Criei o `Request` do Laravel para isolar a regra de validação do formulário do controller. Cloquei `unique` em dois lugares, sendo o primeiro no campo `email` do usuário, e o segundo no `document` da pessoa.

#### Problema

A validação somente funciona pro primeiro caso, enquanto ele não aplica pra segunda. O resultado é levar um exception na cara se o CPF do cara for igual e tentar cadastrar.

https://image.ibb.co/kaTRBK/img.png

#### Controller

```
class RegisterSenderPersonController extends Controller
{
    public function store(SenderPersonUserStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $sender = Sender::create([
            'document' => $request['document'],
            'zipcode' => $request['zipcode'],
            'telephone' => $request['telephone'],
            'birthday' => $request['birthday'],
            'gender' => $request['gender'],
            'city_id' => $city->id,
        ]);

        if($sender->id) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request['name'],
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'sender_id' => $sender->id,
                'password' => $request['password'],
            ]);

            return 'gravou';
        }

        return 'deu ruim';
    }
}
```

#### SenderRequest

```
return [
            'birthday' => 'nullable|date',
            'document' => ['unique:sender', 'required', 'min:11','max:14', new Cpf],
            'email' => 'unique:user|required|min:4|max:35',
            'gender' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'name' => 'required|min:4|max:30',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:20',
            'telephone' => 'required|min:11|max:14',
            'zipcode' => 'required|min:8|max:9',
        ];
```

#### SenderMigration

```
Schema::create('sender', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('company_name', 60)->nullable()->unique();
            $table->string('exhibition_name', 25)->nullable();
            $table->string('document', 14)->unique();
            $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('gender')->nullable();
            $table->string('zipcode', 8);
            $table->string('telephone', 11);
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: você está fazendo `unique` em tabelas diferentes, qual é a tela de erro?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Atualzado !

Comment: Você pode também colocar a parte do controle? Talvez o erro seja no código do controler

Comment: O que `new Cpf` faz?

Comment: Ele valida o CPF. Essa função funciona, pq se digitar o cpf inválido ele retorna uma mensagem de erro pro form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do laravel, é necessário passar mais um parâmetro de coluna nas rules

> **unique:table,column,except,idColumn**
>
> The field under validation must be unique in a given database table. If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.

Tente isso:

```
return [
        'birthday' => 'nullable|date',
        'document' => ['unique:sender,document', 'required', 'min:11','max:14', new Cpf],
        'email' => 'unique:user,email|required|min:4|max:35',
        'gender' => 'nullable|boolean',
        'name' => 'required|min:4|max:30',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|max:20',
        'telephone' => 'required|min:11|max:14',
        'zipcode' => 'required|min:8|max:9',
    ];
```

Comment: Eu mudei, mas permanece com o mesmo comportamento